# Django Subquery doesn't escape dates

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a query that filters registers according to some dates, and uses subqueries to aggregate data. It goes like this:

```
# Parse datetime
st_date = timezone.datetime.strptime(...)
ed_date = timezone.datetime.strptime(...)
# Main queryset
clients = Client.objects.all()
# Subquery
details = Detail.objects.filter(
        temp__client__id=OuterRef('pk'),
        temp__datetime__date__range=(st_date, ed_date))
# Filter brand
brand_values = detalles.filter(
        product__brand__id=...).values(
        'temp__client')
# Aggregate
total_qtys = brand_values.annotate(t=Sum('qty')).values('t')
# Annotate to main query
qs = clients.annotate(brand_1: 
        Subquery(total_qtys, output_field=FloatField()))
```

And it works on my local env, but on production it always returns `null` for all rows. Upon inspection I noticed that the generated query goes like:

```
SELECT ...,
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(U0.`qty`) AS `t`
                 FROM `sales_detail` U0
                        INNER JOIN `sales_temp` U1
                                   ON (U0.`temp_id` = U1.`id`)
                        INNER JOIN `inventory_product` U3
                                   ON (U0.`product_id` = U3.`id`)
                 WHERE (U1.`cliente_id` = (`sales_client`.`id`) AND DATE(
                     CONVERT_TZ(U1.`datetime`, 'UTC',
                                'America/Mexico_City')) BETWEEN 2018-12-01 AND 2018-12-31 AND
                        U3.`brand_id` = 6)
                 GROUP BY U1.`client_id`
                 ORDER BY NULL), 0) AS `brand_1`
FROM `sales_client`
WHERE NOT (`sales_client`.`status_rip` = True)
```

And if I run the raw query against my local db it fails, too. I then noticed that the dates are being unquoted, and the problem is solved by just quoting them, i.e. by replacing 2018-12-01 for '2018-12-01' in the raw query.

So the question is: why doesn't Django quote the dates? and more important: Why does it work only when executed by the ORM?

Edit:

This is the configuration on both local and production

Local:

Fedora 28
Mariadb 10.1.25 running on Docker with the following config:

```
#mariadb.cnf

[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server  = utf8
collation-server      = utf8_general_ci
character_set_server   = utf8
collation_server       = utf8_general_ci

!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Production:

Fedora 24
Mariadb installed from repos, version 10.1.25, with no config. changes

Answer (score 0):

You may not like these answers. `QuerySet.query` is not specific to the database yet. It is the generic version of the query as it may apply to any database. So in that case, you will have to add the quotations to the dates, datetimes and maybe a few other data types. I can't remember which. The cursor is what handles the actual escaping of parameters.

[From Django's code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py):

```
def _execute_query(self):
    connection = connections[self.using]

    # Adapt parameters to the database, as much as possible considering
    # that the target type isn't known. See #17755.
    params_type = self.params_type
    adapter = connection.ops.adapt_unknown_value
    if params_type is tuple:
        params = tuple(adapter(val) for val in self.params)
    elif params_type is dict:
        params = {key: adapter(val) for key, val in self.params.items()}
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Unexpected params type: %s" % params_type)

    self.cursor = connection.cursor()
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)
```

As you can see, the QuerySet nor the Query actually escapes the parameters. It passes them to the database wrapper / cursor to handle as each database may need to do it differently.

In regards to why Production has different results than locally, I would check your data. The code should be generating the same query for the database which means it's most likely the data is causing the different results.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify: The DB I'm using locally is a dump from production so the data is the same. Also, the environment is managed using pipenv so everything from the connector to django are the same. The only thing that varies is th DB version: locally is mariadb-10.2 and on prod is mariadb-10.1. Also I'm running it locally using docker and on prod it was installed using the distro's package manager

Comment: I can take a closer look, but please provide more information about what you're doing on production to get "nulls for all rows" vs locally. Also provide what you do locally and what that provides. Try to generate them from each environment rather than printing what you think you're using on both. From my perspective there's something different between the two and no assumptions should be made when debugging this.

Comment: I'm getting nulls because the subqueries are returning empty rows, because the dates are malformed. The only thing I do different locally vs in production is that it's being run with the DEBUG=1 env var. Nothing else. I tried with the same version of mariadb and the result is the same.

Comment: I saved the result of `pipenv graph` on both local and prod and diff'ed them and the output is empty — no difference. One thing is that prod is Fedora 24 and local is Fedora 28. With prod having mariadb installed from repos and local is using docker. One thing I'm guessing is maybe mariadb was compiled with different flags for the fedora repos and for the docker images?

Comment: None of those should matter. I'm still on the data train. Take the SQL statement that's being generated, add the necessary quotes so it executes. Then break it down and start running individual parts both locally and on production until you find the difference. That's going to be much more likely than some weird bug in the database wrapper and OS versions.

Comment: That's what I did. The difference is that executing the query with the dates without quotes returns 0 registers, i.e. can't find any `detail` between unquoted dates, quoting the dates is the only difference. In the end what I did was removing the `__date` function from the django expression.